# Cache issue / conflict with mobile & desktop themes - Magento Community 1.7

Tags: magento, caching, themes

We’re using Magento Community version 1.7 and have a standard desktop theme and a mobile theme.  We’ve added matched expressions to the General > Design > Themes section to display the relevant theme based on browser user agent.

Everything works great when the cache is switched off.  However, when the cache is switched on and cleared, the theme which is loaded first gets cached.  Is there a way around this?  Either creating a separate cache for each theme or even switching the cache off altogether for the mobile theme?

Many thanks in advance for any advice you can give.

Answer (score 0):

One way to bypass this is to leave the block cache and layouts not cached. These two are probably causing the issue to happen. This won't be that great of a performance hit since Magento is a resource hog anyway. I would recommend enabling Zend Full Page Cache and perhaps even using something like memcached or APC to supplement the default magento caching.

Hope this helps!